# What does `every loop` actually do in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I've seen people always write arrows between nodes with some variation of `\draw[every loop] _blah blah_`. Why is this the case? Removing the `every loop` changes nothing visually for me.

Comment: `every xxx` is a convention related to how TikZ controls styling. There are `every node`, `every picture`, `every axis`, etc.

Comment: To support @Symbol1's comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path foreach \X in {1,...,4}{ (\X,0) node[circle,draw] (\X){}};
\draw foreach \X in {1,2} {(\X) edge[loop above] (\X)};
\draw[every loop/.append style={blue}] foreach \X in {3,4} {(\X) edge[loop above] (\X)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` illustrates that this is a style that affects, well, every loop.